# File size limit for a document in SharePoint is actual file size or file size on disk

Tags: 2007, development, document-library, file

The file size upload limit for a document is 50mb by default but is it file size of the document or file size of document on disk.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this information is relevent? Why not just bump the allotment to a larger size plus a healthy margin for error? Does your SQL store have modified clustering?

Comment: The difference is minuscule, but it is based on the file size not file size on the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comparing disk space, to site collection (Adding removing a site collection) The quota is based on the actual file sizes.

To get the site collection totals:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://sitecollection
$site.Usage.Storage;
$site.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's isn't any big difference at all as said by Hossein Aarabi but limit is for file size not file size on disk as far as I find out by research however couldn't find any reference.